# How to correctly type an IoT Core lambda handler?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

For HTTP lambda, we have the type `APIGatewayEvent`, which works great.

However, for IoT core, I found the `IoTEvent`, but it looks like wrong for typing my lambda.

```
export const handler: Handler = async (event: { data: IoTEvent }) ...
```

My handler receive the first parameter as following:

```
{
  data: 'some string'
}
```

In AWS SDK, is there any type that I could use?

Comment: I don't believe there is any set format for IoT events. They are literally whatever your IoT things are sending, which is entirely up to you. So if you want typing for those events you will need to define the type yourself, and include that type definition in your function's code.